# Where can I find more components to the MDL than on the main website

Tags: material-design-lite

I was looking to make my page better, and I coundn't find many examples of how can I add more complex components to the MDL design. I found single component "mdl-select" and that's it.

Is there any page or gallery of components, even paid, that I can browse and take a look at some showcases other than the main framework provides?

I have browsed the page getmdl.io completely and I find the showcases not that inspiring in comparition to some other material design frameworks such as materializecss.com for example.

Answer (score 1):

[Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/) is not a framework. It is an implementation of Material Design for web by Google and there is no any paid service in Material Design Lite. Here is the full [components](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html) provided by [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/): https://getmdl.io/components/index.html

**Edit:** Here is the custom unofficial mdl-select components by [CreativeIt](http://creativeit.io/):   http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/

Comment: I was looking for more complex components. something like the mdl-select

Comment: @xdeveloper are you looking for custom component? Please do check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try darkboard as showcase of material design library
https://github.com/CreativeIT/material-dashboard-lite

Comment: Add some description here. Once the link is revoked your answer turns invalid.